# How to configure/reference Key/Vault outputs from parent to child module in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to reference certain values based on the key from a module output. For example, I want to only reference or the output of route table from "us-east-1a" AZ to route to its destination and not from all AZs (if multiple).

Here is what I have. This Parent module will automatically create the subnets, route tables, and create those based on how many AZs you reference.

Parent Module:

```
locals {
  private_count = var.enabled == true && var.type == "private" ? length(var.availability_zones) : 0
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count = local.private_count

  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)

  cidr_block = element(var.cidr_block, count.index)

  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = format("%s%s%s", var.name, var.delimiter, element(var.availability_zones, count.index))
      "AZ"   = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
    },
    
  )
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  count = local.private_count

  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  tags = merge(
   
    {
      "Name" = format("%s%s%s-rt", var.name, var.delimiter, element(var.availability_zones, count.index))
      "AZ"   = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
    },
  )
}

#Module      : ROUTE TABLE ASSOCIATION PRIVATE
#Description : Provides a resource to create an association between a subnet and routing
#              table.
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  count = local.private_count

  subnet_id = element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = element(
    aws_route_table.private.*.id,
    var.single_nat_gateway ? 0 : count.index,
  )
}
```

otuputs.tf

```
output "private_route_tables_id" {
  value       = aws_route_table.private.*.id
  description = "The ID of the routing table."
}
```

What this is going to do is create 1:1 mapping for cidr block 1.2.2.2/8 created in "us-east-1a" with its route table and 2.3.3.3/8 created in "us-east-1b" with its route table.

Child Module:

```
module "private_subnets" {
  source = ".../vpc-subnets"

  name                = "subnets"
  nat_gateway_enabled = true

  availability_zones = ["us-east-1a","us-east-1b"]
  vpc_id             = "vpc-123456070
  type               = "private"
  cidr_block         = [1.2.2.2/8, 2.3.3.3/8]
}
```

Now here is the fun. I want to only route everything from "us-east-1a" only and not both.

Still a part of the child module:

```
resource "aws_route" "route" {
  route_table_id = module.private_subnets.private_route_tables_id
  destination_cidr_block = "6.8.3.3/10
  vpc_endpoint_id = "vpce-420495872039"
}
```

Comment: Then use `for_each` instead of `count`. It will be much easier to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Marcin how would I configure that in the parent module output and referenced in child. Also, is it possible to achieve the goal with the initial setup? If so, how would you approach it from its initial setup